# How do I host a discord-.js bot locally

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots, hosting, local

The title basically says it all.
I already have a PC functioning as my server and want to host my bot there.

I'd prefer to not host online as then I need to make sure my token is secure and all online solutions are either paid or have some sort of drawback.

Comment: Just run "node your-main-file.js" and leave the terminal open? If you want, you can try some dedicated node process managers like pm2, but all you really need is to just run your bot's code.

Answer (score 0):

Just put all the files you wanna use in one folder and start the Bot as usual with the cmd (type in node. or node index.js) If you want to make sure your Bot goes automatically online after he crashed, I can recommend you to create and use a .bat with the following in it:

```js
@echo off
echo Starting..
:main
node index.js
echo Restarting Bot..
goto main
```